# Array not reading argument in woocommerce_quantity_input

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-quantity

I am trying to embed unit after quantity box in woocomerce. This can be easily achieved over at product page. To achieve that I have used post meta box and called it in woocommerce product display file ( wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\global\quantity-input.php ) with following code.

```
<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wc_price_per_unit_key', true);?>
```

Now I want to display it on cart page too. There it is not working because get_the_id() is not working there. So I tried to pass the post ID from cart.php page.

```
$product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                                'input_name'  => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                                'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
                                'max_value'   => $_product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $_product->get_stock_quantity(),
                                'min_value'   => '0',
                                'id'          => $product_id,   
                            ), $_product, false );
```

And I added `id` element in `woocommerce_quantity_input` by this code.

```
function woocommerce_quantity_input( $args = array(), $product = null, $echo = true ) {
    if ( is_null( $product ) ) {
        $product = $GLOBALS['product'];
    }

    $defaults = array(
        'input_name'    => 'quantity',
        'input_value'   => '1',
        'max_value'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', '', $product ),
        'min_value'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', '', $product ),
        'step'          => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', '1', $product ),
        'id'            => '1'
    );
    if ( is_null ( $args['id'] ) ) {            
        echo 'asd';
    }
```

In last I `echo 'asd'` to check that `id` argument is coming in `woocommerce_quantity_input` function but `asd` printed proving that array is not reading the element.

**Solution Found**
I was editing cart.php file that was in `wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\cart` it was being mirrored by `\wp-content\themes\testing\woocommerce\cart`. After editing right cart file problem solved.

**New Issue**
Can anyone guide me how to achieve this in custom plugin approach. That is the hardcode editing that I am doing in woocomerce files. Is it possible via any filter to place code in cart.php file and so on.

Comment: To get the ID at the beginning of your question, you could try to use [get_id( )](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#169-178) or  `global $product; $id = $product->id;` instead…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec both of the two didn't worked.